# /usr/lib/apt/methods/ppa could not be found

Tags: 12.10, updates, package-management, ppa

After using Ubuntu 12.10 for two weeks I ran into problems updating the package database. Running `sudo apt-get update` returns the following error:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/ppa could not be found.
```

This might have to do with the custom theme I installed via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/gtk+3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mountain-lion-theme
```

What could cause this error and how can I fix this.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Coudl you upload the **complet** output in paste.ubuntu.com and link it here?

Comment: please include the contents of the relevant file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`